# As per the scriptures, can an adult son retain his Hindu religious identity if his parents were to convert to a different religion?

Tags: dharma

This is not a legal question but need an answer from the scriptural perspective

Comment: Hinduism is a path, not a destination. It's a scale, not binary. There are many "Hindus" who don't live according to Shastras. There are many "Muslims/Christians" who live according to our Shastras, even though they may not know it. For e.g. a 'Hindu' who drinks/porn/gambles/kills/cheats is much less Hinduistic than an orthodox Muslim/Christian/Jew who is god-fearing and helps his community.